Como puedo enlazar Table Plus con mi base de datos SQL Server?
Me pide esto, pero no tengo ni idea de dónde se obtienen esos datos. He logrado conectar mySql, pero mySql Server se me ha hecho imposible

El inicio de sesión a mi base de datos la hago por Sql Server Management Studio 20, y lo hago por autenticación de windows, por lo que no me pide credenciales como un user y password.

Y la doc de esa app no dice como conectarla?? de paso, ahi dice auth.. si lo cambias a windows no cambia la ventana?

he logrado conectar SQL Server con Table Plus. Adjunto imagen:
